# Integral of $1/x$ with x real in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, education

I'd like to get:

$$\int \frac{1}{x} dx = \log |x|$$

in Mathematica. I don't know how impose that $x$ is real. If I run:

```
Integrate[1/x,x]
```

Mathematica gives me $\log (x)$ without absolute value because it considers $x$ as a complex number.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do you want it to give you this answer? Given Mathematica's definition of `Log` its answer is correct for negative values.  If you can explain the problem Mathematica's answer gives you, we may be able to suggest a work around.

Comment: Cross-posted at community.wolfram.  Could you please provide a link?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870141) is a related thread on math.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own function to do so:

```
realIntegrate[f_, x_Symbol] := 
  Simplify[Integrate[f, x] /. Log[expr_] :> Log[Abs[expr]], x ∈ Reals]

realIntegrate[1/x, x]

(* Log[Abs[x]] *)

realIntegrate[2x/(x^2 - 1), x]

(* Log[Abs[x^2 - 1]] *)

realIntegrate[2x/(x^2 + 1), x]

(* Log[x^2 + 1] *)
```

Or if you need `Integrate` to do this, you can overload its definition:

```
Unprotect[Integrate];

Integrate[f_, x_Symbol] /; !TrueQ[$flag] := 
  Block[{$flag = True},
    realIntegrate[f, x]
  ]

Protect[Integrate];

Integrate[1/x, x]

(* Log[Abs[x]] *)

Integrate[2x/(x^2 - 1), x]

(* Log[Abs[x^2 - 1]] *)

Integrate[2x/(x^2 + 1), x]

(* Log[x^2 + 1] *)
```

Comment: In this specific use case, `RealAbs[]` is much better to use than `Abs[]`.