# Is mathematica integrating $\frac{1}{x}$ correctly?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When $x<0, \quad \int \frac{1}{x}\,dx = \ln (-x) + \text{const.}$

*Mathematica* calculates this

```
Assuming[x < 0, Integrate[1/x, x]]
```

as

```
Log[x]
```

(It's understood that *Mathematica* drops the constant, okay, but the argument for the logarithm should be positive!

Any ideas?

Comment: What really matters in practical calculations is the integral, not the antiderivative.

Comment: This has been asked before, I believe. `Log[x]` is the complex logarithm (with a certain standard branch cut, namely, the negative real axis) whose derivative is `1/x` except technically along the branch cut though one can pick a different branch cut*, `Abs[]` is the complex absolute value, and `Log[Abs[x]]` is not complex-differentiable (so it cannot be the antiderivative). *In any case, the different branches differ by a constant; as a general antiderivative therefore, it can be adapted to particular cases.

Comment: also just to address the notion that it should be positive: the argument to the logarithm does not need to be positive, as with $x>0$, $\log(-x) = \log(x) + i\pi$ under Mathematica's chosen branch cut; this can be confusing if you haven't seen the complex logarithm before. but note that if $x,y>0$, and we integrate from $-y$ to $-x$, $\log(-x) - \log(-y) = \log(x) + i\pi - (\log(y) + i\pi) = \log(x) - \log(y)$, so everything works out!

Comment: @yarchik,  hahaha!  The indefinite integral does not matter!  Tell that to all the Calculus I teachers out there!

Comment: Okay, so since $\log x = \log(-x)+\text{const}$, *Mathematica* is returning the correct answer, up to a constant.  Thanks to everybody for the explanations!

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(51863)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51863), [(158849)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/158849)

Comment: @mjw If you want the constant, you should do: `Assuming[x < 0, Integrate[1/x, x, GeneratedParameters -> C]]`

Comment: @flinty, Thank you!

Comment: What if we want to take another branch cut of the logarithm.  How do we do that?

Comment: "another branch cut" - [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44769) shows one possibility.

Comment: @J.M., Thank you!